# Using (joining and selecting from) an Postgres CTE in SQLAlchemy's hybrid_property

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I have a Postgres function loaded in to a database which takes two arguments to fetch some data. I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy's `hybrid_property.expression` to access and make it available in the resulting `select`.

Here's the header of the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION the_func(int, character varying)
RETURNS TABLE (
  mymodel_id int,
  x_const character varying,
  y_const character varying,
  selection_priority int
)
AS ...
```

In SQL, to use it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT
  COALESCE(b.x_const, b.y_const) AS constant,
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN the_func(a.id, 'abc') AS b
  ON b.mymodel_id = a.id;
```

However, I'm struggling to get this into SQLAlchemy:

```py
class MyModel:
    id = sa.Column(sa.Int)

    @hybrid_property
    def the_const(self):
        """Python version..."""
        # ???
    
    @the_const.expression
    def the_const(cls):
        """Use the CTE..."""
        # somehow join? 
        # ...join(
        #         aliased(
        #             func.the_func(MyModel.id, 'abc'),
        #             name="const_func"
        #         )
        #    )...
        return select([text("const_func.constant")]).as_scalar()
```

I think it would be possible to get the CTE into SQLAlchemy's CTE (similar to how the OP does here: [Join on a CTE in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387765/join-on-a-cte-in-sqlalchemy)) but wonder if there's a way to use them when they are already loaded in the DB (as in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of help from [Adding a join to an SQL Alchemy expression that already has a select_from()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291584/adding-a-join-to-an-sql-alchemy-expression-that-already-has-a-select-from) I found a solution

```py
class MyModel:
    id = sa.Column(sa.Int)

    @the_const.expression
    def the_const(cls):
        """Use the CTE..."""

        # Alias the CTE:
        const_func = aliased(
            func.the_func(MyModel.id, 'abc'),
            name="b"
        )

        # Set up the join:
        the_join = cls.__table__
        the_join = the_join.join(
            const_func,
            text("b.mymodel_id") == MyModel.id
        )
        # Finally select using the text() wrapper, from the joined tables
        query = select(
            [text("COALESCE(b.x_const, b.y_const)")]
        ).select_from(the_join)
        return query.as_scalar()
```